# Grouping rows depending on the previous values in vertica

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a table with the following data

[image]

Now I am trying to summarize like this:

[image]

The table is summarized on the basis of group_name. If there is change in the group then the row will be selected otherwise not. Is there any way to do this? I just want hint not the whole query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want hints... not the whole query. 
Then have a look to the CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT analytic function. Writing a query like the one you're looking for is quite easy.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use windowing function on the group_name and then keep the row with unique index and earliest time stamp.